# how can I extract text from second last comma till last comma in mysql?

Tags: mysql

sample text:
Viewpoint Vancouver, 1200 West 73rd Avenue Suite 606, Vancouver, British Columbia, V6P 6G5

I need to extract British Columbia from the text.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work absolutely fine.

```
select substring_index(substring_index('Viewpoint Vancouver, 1200 West 73rd Avenue Suite 606, Vancouver, British Columbia, V6P 6G5',',', -2),',',1)
```

Check out the documentation for Substring Index here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Answer (score 0):

I recomment the solution by MontyPython, but would like to add a regular expression solution. MySQL supports regular expressions starting from [version 8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html), MariaDB has it since [version 10.0.5](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/regexp_replace/). Here's an example for MariaDB:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('...', '.*,(.*),', '\\1');
```

Example:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select REGEXP_REPLACE('Viewpoint Vancouver, 1200 West 73rd Avenue Suite 606, Vancouver, British Columbia, V6P 6G5', '.*,(.*),.*', '\\1');
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_REPLACE('Viewpoint Vancouver, 1200 West 73rd Avenue Suite 606, Vancouver, British Columbia, V6P 6G5', '.*,(.*),.*', '\\1') |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  British Columbia                                                                                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```